# Proper behavior for clients receiving status 307

Tags: android, http, firebase, okhttp

I've been using OkHttp for hitting Nest's Firebase API (I don't like the Firebase SDK since it keeps a socket open, which is power hungry for my purposes). On several of the requests, I'll get a status code 307 to redirect to another URL. This isn't terribly surprising. What *is* surprising is that OkHttp doesn't follow the redirect even if I call `client.setFollowRedirects(true)` and/or `client.setFollowSSLRedirects(true)` both of which default to `true` anyway.

I've copied my version of a `doPut()` method below. If the recursive call isn't there, often times the attempt will do nothing. I'm wondering whether Firebase is using the wrong status code, OkHttp isn't interpreting it correctly, or if this is the correct way to handle this situation. It seems like something is wrong here, but I'm not sure what.

```
public static String doPut(String url, String body, String contentType) throws IOException {
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
  RequestBody requestBody =
      RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), body);
  Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).put(requestBody).build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  if (response.code() == 307) {
    doPut(response.header("Location"), body, contentType);
  }
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Comment: w3 states that "If the 307 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued." Given that I'm leaning toward Firebase using the wrong status code, in which case what should they use? The other redirects say the same thing.

Comment: RFC 7231 doesn't include that clause (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.7). Proper behaviour is to `PUT` to the new location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in OkHttp that handles a redirect while keeping the POST method. This might be a mistake in our design. In the interim, you can work around by handling the redirect in an interceptor. You can use the code you've already written as a starting point; the [interceptors doc](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) may also help.